# How to get a lower bound of the number of numbers left after a sieve?

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory

Is there any (simple) way to get a more usefull bound than >=0 on the number of numbers left after a/any sieve like the sieve of eratosthenes? What material should one read to get knowledge of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by simple. Each sieve is different, and different methods apply. The short answer is *no* --- for instance, one cannot deduce a nontrivial lower bound on an application of the Sieve of Eratosthenes when applied to twim primes. [Doing so would lead to a proof of the twin prime conjecture].

A good book for figuring out how sieves work is *Sieve Methods* by Halberstam. The first sieve considered in detail is the Sieve of Eratosthenes and its various applications.

Comment: So even with slight modifications of existing sieves like eratosthenes but also every composit +1 is sieved, can not find a non trivial bound that is similar to the bound on the old sieve?

Comment: not including the 2 multiples sieve ofcourse

Comment: @MyName If you sieve out the composites and the composites + 1, the only remaining numbers will be 1 and 2.